# scala compiler error on lazy val

Tags: scala

I came across the following error in scala compiler. I couldn't find the issue in jira. Therefore I decided to ask first if this is a known issue:

I started with the following two methods:

```
  def getName: String = getString match {
    case None => return ""
    case Some(str) => return str
  }

  def getString: Option[String] = Some("abc")
```

Then I changed the first method to

```
  lazy val getName: String = getString match {
    case None => return ""
    case Some(str) => return str
  }
```

Unfortunately, I forgot to remove the return statement. In this case, scala compiler should stop with the message "return outside method definition", but what it really did was:

```
[ant:scalac] error: uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.NullPointerException

[ant:scalac] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ant:scalac]    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.Select(Trees.scala:1066)
[ant:scalac]    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.Select(SymbolTable.scala:13)
```

It looks like a bug. Doesn't it?

Comment: Which Scala version do you use? Can you provide a compilable example producing the error?

Comment: My scala version is 2.10.1. The example is here [link](https://github.com/macjankowski/scalatests.git)

Comment: Ok, it is a bug. Just report it on https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Bug reported here: [link](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7352)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a bug, given that the compiler should never just crash, but instead emit compile errors.
Now, your code is not correct either. You have a `return` statement in the context of the expression used to initialize a val. In this context, there is nothing to return from (`return` means return from the enclosing method, but there is no enclsing method here).
What you want is this:

```
lazy val getName: String = getString match {
  case None => ""
  case Some(str) => str
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. The return statement is there on purpose. Otherwise, the NPE would not crop up.